# Picking points on a sphere at random

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution, spheres

Suppose we pick up $N$ points uniformly at random on a sphere. The probability that these points lie within a 'fixed' hemisphere is easily calculated to be $1/2^N$.  But what is the probability that all the points lie within *any* hemisphere on the sphere? 
I am actually interested in this question for $d$-dimensional hypersphere as well, so method of computation that extends to higher dimensions will be much appreciated.

Comment: This was investigated by the inimitable Kevin S. Brown [here](http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath327/kmath327.htm)

Comment: Thank you! Its a brilliant solution.

Comment: That was indeed wonderful!

Comment: Some visualization here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OkmNXy7er84

Answer (score 3):

Kevin S. Brown proved in "N points on sphere all in one hemisphere", that the probability that $N$ points, chosen uniformly at random on a $d$-dimensional sphere, are lying all in one hemisphere is:

$$\frac{\Sigma_{k = 0}^{d}C_{n - 1}^k}{2^{n - 1}}$$

Comment: Should $\rm N$ and $N$ in the first line both be $n$ ?

Answer (score 3):

I've wondered about this problem too, and it's a bit difficult to find information on it. Seeing as this is one of the main search results for this problem, I'll put some information here. This problem is known as [Wendel's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wendel%27s_theorem). As mentioned before, Brown proves the formula [here](http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath327/kmath327.htm), but he uses arguments on the polynomial degree of the solution and lacks in geometrical arguments. Wendel's proof is more geometrical in nature and can be found [here](https://www.mscand.dk/article/view/10655/8676). However, an alternative proof which I find more geometrically intuitive is given below.

Let $P(n,d)$ be the probability that $n$ points chosen uniformly at random on $S^d$ lie within a hemisphere. A hemisphere can be parametrized by its apex point $x$, so that the hemisphere is given by $H(x)=\{s\in S^d:s\cdot x>0\}$. While $H(x)$ is defined for $x\in S^d$, we may extend this to $x\in\mathbb{R}^{d+1}-0$ by the same definition, noting $H(x)=H(x/|x|)$. We will need the following lemma, which says that if a set lies in two hemispheres, then it is contained within any hemisphere whose apex lies along the (shortest) great arc between the apices of the two hemispheres.

**Lemma.** If $A\subseteq H(x)\cap H(x')$, then $A\subseteq H(tx+(1-t)x')$ for $t\in[0,1]$.

*Proof*. Let $p\in H(x)\cap H(x')$. Then $p\cdot x>0$ and $p\cdot x'>0$, so $p\cdot(tx+(1-t)x')=tp\cdot x+(1-t)p\cdot x'>0$. Thus, $p\in H(tx+(1-t)x')$. Q.E.D.

Now, label the $n$ points $p_1,\ldots,p_n$. We can assume $p_1,\ldots,p_{n-1},\pm p_n$ are distinct since it is a.s. true. Let $A_n=\{p_1,\ldots,p_{n-1},p_n\}$, and let $A_n'=\{p_1,\ldots,p_{n-1},-p_n\}$. If either $A_n$ or $A_n'$ lie within a hemisphere, then so does $A_{n-1}$. On the other hand, if $A_{n-1}$ lies in a hemisphere then a.s. one of $p_n,-p_n$ lie within the same hemisphere. Thus, the probability that one of $A_n,A_n'$ lie within a hemisphere is $P(n-1,d)$.

If $A_n\subseteq H(x)$ and $A_n'\subseteq H(x')$, then by the lemma above, $A_{n-1}\subseteq H(tx+(1-t)x')$ for $t\in[1,0]$. Since $p_n\cdot x>0$ and $-p_n\cdot x'>0$, there is some $z\in\{tx+(1-t)x':t\in[0,1]\}$ such that $p_n\cdot z=0$. On the other hand, if $A_{n-1}\subseteq H(z)$ where $p_n\cdot z=0$, then by perturbing $z$ above or below the equator, we can choose $x,x'$ such that $A_n\subseteq H(x)$ and $A_n'\subseteq H(x')$ since $A_{n-1}$ is closed. Thus, both $A_n$ and $A_n'$ lie within hemispheres iff $A_{n-1}\in H(z)$ for some $p_n\cdot z=0$.

Let $f:S^d-\{\pm p_n\}\rightarrow S^{d-1}$ be projection onto the equator $\{s\in S^d:p_n\cdot s=0\}$ (explicitly, this is projection along the axis through $p_n$ to $D^d-0$, followed by radial projection onto $S^{d-1}$). Then the points of $f(A_{n-1})$ have a uniform distribution, and the hemispheres of $S^{d-1}$ correspond to hemispheres $H(z)$ on $S^d$ with $p_n\cdot z=0$. Thus, the probability that both $A_n,A_n'$ lie within hemispheres is $P(n-1,d-1)$.

The probability that $A_n$ lies in a hemisphere is the same as the probability that $A_n'$ lies in a hemisphere, which is $P(n,d)$. By the addition rule,
\begin{equation}
P(n,d)=\frac{P(n-1,d)+P(n-1,d-1)}{2}.
\end{equation}
Now obviously, $P(n,0)=\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$ and $P(1,d)=1$. By the recurrence relation above, $P(n,d)$ is determined solely by these values. Comparing with
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\sum_{k=0}^d\binom{n-1}{k}
\end{equation}
we see that they obey the same recurrence relation and have the same values when $d=0$ and when $n=1$, so they are equal.