# Probability of $n$ points uniformly distributed on $S^{m-1}$ lying on the same hemisphere

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $S^{m-1}$ be the $m-1$ dimensional sphere embedded in $\mathbb{R}^m$. Let $n$ points uniformly distributed on $S^{m-1}$. What is the probability that all $n$ points lie on the same hemisphere?

Comment: It looks like this has been discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1715135/picking-points-on-a-sphere-at-random).